# How to change DataGrip settings so that it detects double quotes as strings instead of columns?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase, rapidsql, datagrip

I just started using Jetbrains DataGrip at work for Sybase DB developement. All the developement is done using ASE ISQL or RapidSQL. they both accept `select "test"` as valid command and print `test` but if i run the same command in DataGrip it detects `"test"` as a column name and gives me `[42S22][207] Invalid column name 'test'.` error. Now i know that i should use single quotes for string but there is a lot of legacy code that i have to maintain and extend that was coded using double quotes for strings

So my question is: Is there any settings that i can change on DataGrip so that it will behave like other two IDEs ?

Comment: `set quoted_identifier off` should fix the issue

Comment: How do I set this option permanently

Comment: check how you are establishing the connection between DataGrip and ASE. you have set the option somewhere there.

Comment: once you set this option off, it is always off, right?

Comment: you have to set it off for each console or each script file

Comment: @GurbakhshishSingh watch'n'vote this issue please https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2606